# Potential memory leak, getting subvector

Tags: c++, vector, indexing, memory-leaks, valgrind

I keep getting information of potential memory leak from valgrind in line where I'm trying to get subvector ( I just don't need first 8 value and 2 last) and simply ... I have no idea how to fix it. For all the help I will be eternally grateful : ). Data is `std::optional<std::vector<uint8_t>>`
and rawData is simply `std::vector<uint8_t>`.

```
auto data = getValueFromMemoryAddress(memoryAddress + static_cast<uint32_t>(rawData.size()));

if (data.has_value()) {
    rawData.insert(rawData.end(), data.value().begin() + 8, data.value().end() - 2); 
 }
```

[img of valgrind output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5mut.png)

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: *I have no idea how to fix it.* -- You shouldn't write code where you have "no idea how to fix it" if something goes wrong.  The original programmer should never get into a position where the code they have written is not understandable by the original programmer, thus "can't be fixed".  Unless you show a full example, you wrote the code to introduce the error, so unwrite that code and rewrite the code so that you understand fully what the code is supposed to do and that it can be easily diagnosed by yourself.

Comment: Is 'data' heap allocated, if so you need to delete it with operator delete[].

Comment: Please run your application in a terminal and copy/paste the Valgrind error here.

Answer (score 0):

Your application seems to be throwing an exception. You need to figure out what your priorities are: fixing the exception so that your application executes correctly or resolving the probable leak detected by Valgrind when your application is crashing.

Looking at your code, if `data` has a length of 10 or less then the range of values being inserted will be zero (hopefully that does nothing, but you should check) or negative (which is almost certainly very bad).

So my guess is that you need to write something like

`if (data.has_value() && data.size() > 10) {`

Getting back to the leak, you need to look at what exception handling is being done, if any. If you are getting a crash because of corrupted memory then it is perfectly likely that cleanup code is not getting executed and the memory for the exception is not being freed.